# Google analytics event tracking - make the reports user friendly

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

GA: content>event>overview>**event label**.

I am using download tracker and I would like to make my reports "user friendlier", 
the problem is, **"this.href"** function provide the "label" section in GA the name, which in that case takes the whole url (href="http://nameTheWebsite*/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/somethingToRead.pdf") and I would like to see only  "somethingToRead.pdf" in my report.

the tracking code is:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Download','PDF', this.href]);"
```

I am using WP. 
now, I did some homework, and I believe that `substr(this.href , -10)` function could help but I don't know how to do it right.

Any help would be highly appreciatedץ 
Thanks in advance.

Gal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`substr(this.href, -10)` will only work correctly, whenever the filename is accidentially 10 characters long.

A more sophisticated solution would be something like this:

```
var page = this.href.splitOnLast('/'); // this should return an array with two elements: path and filename
page = (page.length > 1) ? page[1].substr(1) : page[0]; // just in case there is no / in the this.href
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Download','PDF', page]);
```

Now you should get "somethingToRead.pdf" in your Google Analytics tracking.